# Generate a matrix with predefined probability of occurrence for each possible value

Tags: matlab, probability-density

How do you generate a matrix with a predefined probability of occurrence for each possible value? For example, I need to generate a *3*-by-*5* matrix consisting of only `1`, `0` and `-1`, where the probability of occurrence of `1`  is `0.25`, the probability of occurrence of `-1`  is `0.25` and the probability of occurrence of `0`  is `0.5`?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is:

```
round(rand(3,5)*2)-1
```

more generally you have to find a function that produces random variables according to your probability distribution. Then you can use `reshape()` to get the right array.

Comment: got it.thank you all